# How i Batch update in Spring data neo4j 6 Using UNWIND query?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

In SDN 6, the UNWIND query does not work so anyone tell me how I batch update in Spring data neo4j 6?

Comment: Hello, you'll need to add more details about what you've tried.
What query did you try to run? What's the code running it? What exact version of Spring Data Neo4j 6?

Comment: Also, for any batch insertion, the overhead of Object-Graph Mappers is usually not worth it. You would probably be better off using SDN's Neo4jClient or use the underlying Neo4j Java driver directly.

Comment: Hi fbiville, I add all detail about query,model and error regarding SDN 6. Also i use SDN 6.2.1 version. Please follow below link which i mention detail.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2576

Comment: If you solved the problem in a GitHub issue, I don't think there is a reason to keep the question here anymore. What do you think?

Comment: Hi fbiville, I apologize that I forgot to tell you that the issue is resolved by Mr.Simons. Again thank you so much for giving the fast reply. We Really appreciated it.